# Creating a CNN for object detection

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow, object-detection

I want to create a convolutional neural network to identify a particular object in an image, say a guitar. I know there are a lot of posts and answers about this but I'm very new to this field and am not being able to find a simple explanation. If I have the coordinates for any guitar in an image how do I convert that to vector/tensor can someone please tell me?? 
Just a few steps as to what I should do next would be very helpful! Thanks!

Comment: you need a lot of guitar images. there's a large number of examples in internet with MNIST sample, that recognizes digits. I'd start with them

Answer (score 1):

To train a neural network you need lots of examples (10'000s typically) where you have the correct answer.

More generally, I like the explanation by [Ujjwal Karn](https://ujjwalkarn.me/2016/08/11/intuitive-explanation-convnets/) and [Adit Deshpande](https://adeshpande3.github.io/A-Beginner%27s-Guide-To-Understanding-Convolutional-Neural-Networks/).

After that, Tensorflow has good tutorials. Starting with [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners) will be a good start so that you will understand the following tutorials on CNN's ([this](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros) and this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers)) better.